# Excel Worksheet reference in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently working on a workbook which has a 52 worksheets, 1 for week of the year. I'm trying to make a worksheet that i can use as a quick-check for each of the worksheets. I'm wondering if there's a way of having just 1 worksheet pull data in from each of the other sheets ? or do i have to create one for every week individually ?

For example,

instead of individual sheets with a load of '=VLOOKUP(B3,'WEEK 12'!$A$4:$E$40,3,FALSE)'
is there any i can have the formula use whichever worksheet name i have in say cell c1 ? like '=VLOOKUP(B3,'**Cell C1**'!$A$4:$E$40,3,FALSE)'

Sorry for being a bit long winded, and hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Google indirect() Excel. To hard to write a complete answer on my phone

Comment: Thanks, will have a go at using it in my vlookup formulas

Comment: What am i doing wrong with the formula...    =VLOOKUP('Lookup'!B3, INDIRECT("'" & $C$1 &"')!$A$4:$E$40,3,FALSE)

Comment: It depends on what you have in c1, but I think you need: =VLOOKUP(B3,INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!A4:E20"),3,FALSE) where your contents of c1 has something like this: WEEK 12

Comment: Assuming that "WEEK 12" is in C1, here is what is wrong with your formula:
1. There is no close quote after the second open quote.
2. It looks like you want to enclose only the $C$1 inside the parentheses. If you do that the indirect cell reference will be incomplete, only referencing the sheet name.
So, after the 2nd & (and before the comma) you want the following (including the double and single quotes):
"'!$A$4:$E$40")


As mentioned elsewhere, you don't need the $ signs since these references are pure text fields and will not change nor automatically be updated if the cell is moved.

Answer (score 2):

As you are now using a text representation of columns A and E, there is absolutely no need for the $ markers.

```
=vlookup(b3, indirect(text(c1, "'@'!\A\:\E")), 3, false)
```

Alternately, with just *12* in C1.

```
=vlookup(b3, indirect(text(c1, "'w\e\ek 0'!\A\:\E")), 3, false)
```

Comment: yeah, my eyes haven't woken up yet.

Comment: I use formats like this to change totals into column headings, but I have not considered using them to potentially allow a numeric field to act like a label in an indirect cell reference.  Nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

For example, where C1 might contain `WEEK 12`,

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!$A$4:$E$40"),3,FALSE)
```