# Excel - create sync workbooks to master spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365, excel-2016

Need help. 
I have over 20 different excel sheets with macro enabled .

I need to create master spreadsheet sheet that can handle live data sync from other worksheets.

E.g I need to link 20 columns from each worksheet and output those into master spreadsheet, so if anyone updates one of those spread sheet, it will auto update master spreadsheet as well.

Multiple people will be working at the same time.

Is this something excel can handle on its own or do I need to get another program? - MS Access would create more overhead for me.

Can anyone suggest solution? Program?

Files are located in SharePoint library.

Comment: Have you searched on here for similar questions? one was asked this morning?

Comment: Was it? Let me do some digging..

Comment: can't find what I was looking for, but you may find this interesting - in terms of the answers... : https://stackoverflow.com/q/51231410/4961700

Comment: That's such a broad question that it's near impossible to give you any information - especially with no real idea as to the scope of this project or your skill level.  Generally when someone wants data summarized in Excel, they build a worksheet to summarize it, sort of like any other spreadsheet you build.

Comment: Would PowerBI help?

Comment: I was to resolve the issue by using PowerBI. Required training on users end.

Comment: was able to do special copy/paste link from excel. so far its working.